# Next auth session disappearing data in development environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am using next auth in my next.js project,
but during development, if the server refreshes then the sessio immediately loses the data in it, also if I change to another tab in the browser and then return back to it, the session loses its data, and I will be forced to sign out then sign in to let it work again.
This doesn't happen in production mode.
below it the `[...nextauth].js` file code:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import axios from "axios";
let userInfo = {};
export default NextAuth({
  site: process.env.SITE,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        let status;
        let user = {};
        let message = ''
        await axios
          .post(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN_URL}/app/auth`,
            { userName: credentials.username.replace(/\s/g, ''), pwd: credentials.password },
            {
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
              withCredentials: true,
            }
          )
          .then(function (response) {
            if (response?.data) {
              user = { ...response.data };
              userInfo = user;
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            if (error.response) {
              throw new Error(JSON.stringify({ errors: error?.response?.data?.message, status: false }))
            } else if (error.request) {
              throw new Error(JSON.stringify({ errors: 'Server error, please try again.', status: false }))

            } else {
            
              throw new Error(JSON.stringify({ errors: 'Network error, please try again.', status: false }))

            }
          });
        return user;
      },
    }),

  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/Auth/Login",
  },
  session: {
    jwt: true,
    strategy: "jwt"
  },
  jwt: {
   
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 6,
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET,

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      user && (token = { ...token, ...user });
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user = { ...userInfo };
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the same exact situation, but this is the only thread I could find with a similar issue. I was also getting the error message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'JWT' of undefined"

What led to it was that my backend would return a login response structured like so:

```
{ user: {}, jwt: "string" }
```

I was hoping to structure the final next-auth session object like:

```
session = { expires, jwt: "string", user: {} }
```

But that's when I kept running into the issue. I'd sign in successfully, but the session cookie would immediately disappear whenever focus was shifted away and then back to it. I was driving myself crazy until I started restructuring the session object. I eventually decided to go with *my* less ideal structure of:

```
session = { expires, user: { ...user, jwt: "string" } }
```

And finally, it started working.